# Firewall with layer 3 switch or without it?

Tags: networking, cisco-asa, architecture, switch

I am trying to make a *simple* network architecture for a small company.

One of the sites is built of a firewall (to create a DMZ, to make the VPN between the sites) and three switches, like in link below.

[image]

There are workstations connected to each of the switches. It is a VLAN-based network. Employees obtain their addresses with DHCP server. The company has got also another site, connected with a VPN/IPSec tunnel.

My question is, would it be reasonable to use a layer 3 Switch as SW3? I would then configure the DHCP server and routing inside the site on SW3, leaving ASA for things related with DMZ and VPN.

Or do you think using a layer 2 switch will be enough as SW3, and make all the routing and DHCP configurations on ASA?

Thank you for every answer. I am just afraid it is not worth it doing it with layer 3 switch and a firewall. 
If you know some literature about creating an architecture I would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List pros and cons for both scenarios and decide. Only you can know which option is best as you know what your environment requirements are.
I will start :

### With Layer 3 switch

- Less load on the ASA
- ASA only deals with external traffic
- all LAN subnets are contained withing the switches.

### Without Layer 3 switch

- No need to buy layer 3 switch
- All of the internal network is exposed to ASA
- You can filter internal traffic using ASA if needed.

etc..

Comment: Yes, this is in general the thing I am considering, that there are pros for both approaches. I only was not sure if in general it is worth being considered. Thank you for ensuring!

Comment: If you have heavy inter-vLAN traffic you should more heavily consider the L3 Switch design as the ASA will quickly become a bottleneck. If this is not the case without the L3 Switch would be simpler and cheaper.